# Facebook mobile for Droid unable to delete friends

Tags: facebook

How does one go about deleting friends via the Droid's Facebook application? I am running the latest build of Facebook.

Comment: You mean ***Android***, don't you? As far as I know there isn't a Droid-specific Facebook app.

Comment: @AlEverett The device was the Droid, as the apps function differently on different devices.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I don't know that this is still the case. I've updated the Facebook app from the Market a couple of times now and I don't see a Droid-specific version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can, at least at this time.

Not particularly surprising. Their app just sends you to m.facebook.com for anything more than basic functionality.

Comment: I will leave this open until end of day and mark this as the answer if this remains the case.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Viewing their profile touch the friends tab, a menu should pop up and at the bottom should be the option to "unfriend".  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it using the Droid app. The only way is to use Facebook's mobile webapp. Find the friend you want to delete, then scroll down and find the remove friend option.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes if you are viewing your news feed, you are seeing posts from a profile you are not necessarily friends with, you just "liked" something of theirs which will then add to your news feed. In THAT case you go to their profile and "unlike" them. That should stop them from posting to your wall.